# When to add @Suspendable to methods in a flow?

Tags: corda

Whats the best practice here to annotate a method as `@Suspendable`? In a Flow, there may be multiple private methods that query the vault/ compute business logic. Should these be annotated with `@Suspendable` so it can recover if a node crashes midway?

Or is `@Suspendable` only for methods where `send` / `sendAndReceived` are involved where its waiting for responses from counterparties?

Comment: Anything that initiates flow with other nodes or notary. Eg: A function that calls SubFlow(This flow initiates sessions with other nodes.) The function should be annotated with @Suspendable else I see quasar errors all over.

Comment: What about just normal methods that just do query/computation? Any benefits from adding @Suspendable?

Comment: I don't think so. I couldn't find any functions in CordaRPCOps.kt annotated with @Suspendable. so basically functions like sub-flow, sendReceive etc that are marked with suspendable should be called from functions that are itself marked suspendable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [paralleluniverse](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#suspendable):

> The run methods in Fiber, SuspendableRunnable, and SuspendableCallable
> declare that they may throw a SuspendExecution exception.
>
> @Suspendable is our way to specify a suspendable method is by declaring throws SuspendExecution.This is convenient because SuspendExecution is a checked exception, so if f calls g and g is suspendable, the Java compiler will force us to declare that f is suspendable (and it must be because it calls g and g might be suspended).
>
> Sometimes, however, we cannot declare f to throw SuspendExecution. One example is that f is an implementation of an interface method, and we cannot (or don’t want to) change the interface so that it throws SuspendExecution.
>
> So, suppose method f is declared in interface I, and we’d like to make its implementation in class C suspendable. The compiler will not let us declare that we throw SuspendExecution because that will conflict with f’s declaration in I.
>
> What we do, then, is annotate C.f with the @Suspendable annotation (in the co.paralleluniverse.fibers package). Assuming C.f calls park or some other suspendable method g – which does declare throws SuspendExecution, we need to surround f’s body with try {} catch(SuspendExecution) just so the method will compile.
>
> if we want to run h in a fiber, then it must be suspendable because it calls f which is suspendable. We could designate h as suspendable either by annotating it with @Suspendable or by declaring SuspendExecution

If we want any method to run in a fiber, then it must be suspendable.
so basically, any method that calls a method which can throw SuspendExecution or is annotated with  `@Suspendable`.

In my case I faced error calling `SubFlow` from a function, since I didn't annotate it with `@Suspendable` I faced Quasar Exceptions. As `SubFlow` is annotated with `@Suspendable` annotating my function helped get rid of those errors.
Error:  `Uninstrumented whole methods ('**') or single calls ('!!') detected:`